# Knitr plot doesn't have axes when viewed in Evince (updated RStudio, R, and Texlive)

Tags: r, latex, knitr

In the following MWE, my plots have no axes at all when compiled in RStudio. However, when I do `knit2pdf("myfile.Rnw")` and compile the resulting .tex document, everything works fine. Why? UPDATED: the problem only happens inside Ubuntu 14.04 Evince (GNOME Document Viewer 3.10.3). When opened in Okular for example, everything works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
plot(rnorm(100))
@
\end{document}
```

Rstudio Version 0.98.1028 (latest)

Output of `sessionInfo()` inside a R chunk

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=C
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=C
LC_TELEPHONE=C
LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats
graphics grDevices utils
datasets
methods
other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.6
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] evaluate_0.5.5 formatR_0.10
highr_0.3
[5] tools_3.1.1
```

From within `knitr`:

```
Sys.which('pdflatex'); cat(system('pdflatex --version', intern = TRUE), sep = '\n')
pdflatex
"/opt/texbin/pdflatex"
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)
kpathsea version 6.2.0
Copyright 2014 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty. Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.6.10; using libpng 1.6.10
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03
```

From terminal:

```
anh@anh-IdeaPad-Y570:~$ which pdflatex; pdflatex --version
/opt/texbin/pdflatex
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)
kpathsea version 6.2.0
Copyright 2014 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.6.10; using libpng 1.6.10
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03
```

[image: Screenshot of plot without axes]

Comment: no, not expected, can't reproduce here (R-devel, knitr 1.6, `knit2pdf()` from R console).  results of `sessionInfo()`?  Are you building via the 'compile PDF' button in RStudio, or by loading `knitr` and using `knit2pdf` or ... ?  Have you started a clean/`--vanilla` R session?

Comment: @BenBolker I just posted `sessionInfo()`. I restarted R session but same result. I use the `compile PDF` button in RStudio.

Comment: @BenBolker So I tried `knit2pdf("myfile.Rnw")` then compile the resulting tex and it works fine. So it's something with RStudio then?

Comment: Sounds that way.  Maybe ask on the RStudio forums?  Although it might be worth seeing if someone here has an answer (good idea to update your question with this information, and the RStudio version too).  At least now you have a workaround ...

Comment: Would try wrapping print() around grid object.

Comment: @BondedDust `print()` is not relevant in this case. @Heisenberg Can you put `sessionInfo()` in the Rnw document and show the output? The `sessionInfo()` without add-on packages loaded is not very useful. It is even better to show some screenshots. At the moment, I cannot reproduce your problem with the latest version of RStudio.

Comment: @Yihui I updated the `sessionInfo()`. A clue I got is that when I ran `knit2pdf()`, there's an error `/usr/bin/texi2dvi: not found`. I know that `texi2dvi` can be installed via `sudo apt-get install texinfo`, but since I installed vanilla texlive (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu), I'm struggling to find out how to fix it. In `tlmgr`, the package manger of texlive, `texinfo` is installed.

Comment: I think `knit2pdf` is a red herring too, since you can run `knit()` and compile the LaTeX manually and get reasonable results.  I think it's most likely something about the graphics settings/state in RStudio (try Help/About menu options to get your RStudio version)?

Comment: I tend to agree with @BenBolker. I also installed vanilla texlive from source, and I had no problems with `apt-get install texinfo`. Anyway, I do not think texi2dvi is relevant here. Please post your RStudio version (please upgrade if you haven't done so), as well as the output of `Sys.which('pdflatex'); cat(system('pdflatex --version', intern = TRUE), sep = '\n')` in Rnw. Then also include a copy of the output `which pdflatex; pdflatex --version` from your terminal. If possible, please make a screenshot of the problematic PDF.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed the issue without being able to truly understand the cause. (My apology to everyone who has spent time to help). I just installed `texlive 2014` (the version I had before was `texlive 2013`, which is frozen at this point), and everything works fine.

I don't think it's `texi2dvi`, since running `knit2pdf()` still spits out that `texi2dvi not found` error despite everything working.

My RStudio version did not change either (0.98.953, with the latest version 0.98.1028).

I did not touch any options in RStudio. The only thing that was changed is upgrading texlive from 2013 to 2014.

If I don't have an important document to write right now I'd be tempted to reinstall texlive and recreate the issue.

Comment: don't think you need to apologize.  It doesn't seem as though you've done anything outright silly, and odd things do happen from time to time in a complex system (Google "Clarke's Law" ...)

Comment: But you do have a larger chance of being hit by Clarke's Law if you live (by choice) outside of the (widely tested) parameters of your distro.  My `texi2dvi` does not go missing, but I also live with Debian's / Ubuntu texlive packaging...